# Button on click Not Connecting to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, button

I am trying connect my button in my html to my javascript file. I have been using this method for weeks and all of a sudden it stopped working and now I am receiving an error, "will_be_set_after_endpoints_apis_loaded is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick" and when I changed it to a function call like "greetByName();" it says method not defined which makes me think that the javascript file isn't being recognized. I will share snippets of my code:

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <title>FLINDER</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="hello.js"></script>

<!--  Load the Google APIs Javascript client library -->
<!--  Then call the init function, which is defined in hello.js -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init">
 </script>
 </head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <P><input id="input_greet_name" type="button" value="Please wait..." 
  onclick="will_be_set_after_endpoints_apis_loaded"></P>
```

JS File:

```
 package com.google.training.helloworld;

 //<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

  function init() {

// You need to pass the root path when you load your API
// otherwise calls to execute the API run into a problem

// rootpath will evaulate to either of these, depending on where the 
 app is running:
// //localhost:8080/_ah/api
// //your-app-id/_ah/api

var rootpath = "//" + window.location.host + "/_ah/api";

// Load the helloworldendpoints API
// If loading completes successfully, call loadCallback function
gapi.client.load('helloworldendpoints', 'v1', loadCallback, rootpath);
}

/*
  * When helloworldendpoints API has loaded, this callback is called.
 * 
 * We need to wait until the helloworldendpoints API has loaded to
 * enable the actions for the buttons in index.html,
 * because the buttons call functions in the helloworldendpoints API */


        function loadCallback () {  
      // Enable the button actions
       enableButtons ();
        }

function enableButtons () {
// Set the onclick action for the first button
//btn = document.getElementById("input_greet_generically");
//btn.onclick= function(){greetGenerically();};

// Update the button label now that the button is active
//btn.value="Submit";

// Set the onclick action for the second button
btn = document.getElementById("input_greet_name");
btn.onclick= function(){greetByName();};

// Update the button label now that the button is active
btn.value="Submit";
}
function greetByName () {

         var loc;
         var sal;
         var schoolTypes;
         var request;
         loc = document.getElementById("loc").value;
         sal = document.getElementById("sal").value;
         var temp = loc;
         schoolTypes = document.getElementById("schoolTypes").value;
         var temps = schoolTypes;
         if(loc == "" || sal == "" || schoolTypes == "")
         {
         alert("Please enter all valid options");
        request = gapi.client.helloworldendpoints.sayHello();
         }
}
```

Comment: *clears throat* you don't have an element with ID "input_greet_name".

Comment: Either that or you didn't post your whole code, which is the absolute basics of asking a question

Comment: `package`?! Java isn't JavaScript!

Comment: I saw that too, but what with all the JavaScript frameworks, who knows if that's correct at this point or not. It's a reserved word in strict mode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Comment: You should put the `meta` element inside the `head` element.

Comment: @evolutionxbox are you saying that would affect the call

Comment: @Jack no I don't think it would. - btw `will_be_set_after_endpoints_apis_loaded` isn't a function, and you need to call it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I know but the method was working before. It came from a default github project and was working until now. Wasn't sure how it worked but even if I call a function that does exist I still get the same error